# Definite Integration Scaling

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Probably a very easy question, sorry.
Suppose we fix some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and some integrable function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$.
Consider $f_\lambda(x) = f(\lambda x)$. I want to show that $f(\lambda x)$ is integrable of $[\tfrac{a}{\lambda},\tfrac{b}{\lambda}]$, and:
$$\int_{(\tfrac{a}{\lambda})}^{(\tfrac{b}{\lambda})} f_\lambda =
\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_a^b f$$
How would I go about showing this from partitions? 
(I have shown multiplication by a constant:
$\int_a^b \lambda f = \lambda \int_a^b f$, and I tried the same approach. Would I just show it through summations again? I am not quite sure how this translates to an interval and its partition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=\{x_0,\dots,x_N\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ and $\xi_k\in[x_{k-1},x_k]$. Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^Nf(\xi_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})&=\lambda\sum_{k=1}^Nf\Bigl(\lambda\,\frac{\xi_k}{\lambda}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{x_k}{\lambda}-\frac{x_{k-1}}{\lambda}\Bigr)\\
&=\lambda\sum_{k=1}^Nf_\lambda\Bigl(\frac{\xi_k}{\lambda}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{x_k}{\lambda}-\frac{x_{k-1}}{\lambda}\Bigr).
\end{align}The first summation is a Riemann sum for $\int_a^bf$, and the last one for $\int_{a/\lambda}^{b/\lambda}f_\lambda$.